# Variably selecting columns in a csv file based on function arguments in r

Tags: r, function, sorting, csv

I am new to both r and stackoverflow, so please bear with me.

I have a .csv file with three columns, 'Date', 'Event', and 'Attendance'. I am attempting to create a function which will allow for the selection of either the Date and Event columns, or the Date and Attendance columns based on the function argument value:

```
imported_csv <- read.csv(name.csv)

column_sort <- function(parameter){
    parsed_data <- imported_csv[c('Date', parameter)]
}
```

This results in parsed_data having a value of 0. I assume this is a formatting issue, as when I run the specific command

```
parsed_data <- imported_csv[c('Date', 'Attendance')
```

Parsed_data contains the values of interest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you call the `column_sort` function ?

Comment: @rawr i think this works without the `return`. there's nothing wrong with the function. i think something else is going on. are you sure your data frame is importing correctly?

Comment: good point. like math asked, how are you using the function? `column_sort('Attendance')`?

Comment: Yes, I am calling using column_sort('Attendance') @rawr and I believe my data frame is importing correctly

Comment: Can you show us the part of code where you use the function, with its context.

Comment: @Math You were likely correct in stating that it was being called incorrectly. I reformatted the my code a bit and now the function works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You need to specify columns when indexing by adding a comma before.  Indexing goes like this: data.frame[row, column].  Also, set your function to return something.

```
imported_csv <- data.frame('Date' = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 30),
                           'Event' = 1:30,
                           'Attendance' = sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 20), 30))

column_sort <- function(parameter){
    parsed_data <- imported_csv[ , c('Date', parameter)]
    return(parsed_data)
}

out <- column_sort('Event')

out

#         Date Event
# 1 2000-01-01     1
# 2 2000-02-01     2
# 3 2000-03-01     3
# 4 2000-04-01     4
# 5 2000-05-01     5
# 6 2000-06-01     6
```